# I have a split() input of different types(int and str), when I try to perform mathematical operations I get an error message

Tags: python

I have a split() function of different types of user input values. When I try to perform mathematical operations on the int types, I get an error saying "unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'"

I've tried placing int before the mathematical operations but I still get some sort of the same error message

```
integer = int(input("N> "))
f_or_b,change_min,hours,current_min = (input("INPUT> ").split())

if (f_or_b == 'F'):
    if (int(change_min + current_min) > 60):
        m = int(60 - (change_min + current_min))
        print(m)
```

I want to be able to input something like: F 20 23 50
and receive an output of 10 (since 20 + 50 > 60, 60 - sum = 10)

Answer (score 1):

`change_min` and `current_min` will be strings. So, `change_min + current_min` will do `string concatenation` and `not mathematical addition`.

---

Try to understand the below code:

```
a, b = input().split()

print(a + b)

print(int(a) + int(b))
```

Input:

```
1 2
```

Output:

```
12
3
```

---

Your code should be something like:

```
if f_or_b == 'F':
    if (int(change_min) + int(current_min)) > 60:
        m = 60 - (int(change_min) + int(current_min))
        print(m)
```

Or you can convert:

```
change_min = int(change_min)
current_min = int(current_min)
```

And then use them as integers like `change_min + current_min`.